# jQuery filter items by multiple attributes and with range

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

OK, I have been breaking my head around this for too long, and I can't seem to find a solution here as my case is a little different from other questions on SO.

I am using two 'filters' with checkboxes that users can check to view certain items (and hide the others that don't match those filters).

The following html code contains the filters:

```
<div class="filters">
    <p>Sex</p>
    <label><input name="sex" type="checkbox" value="Male">Male</label>
    <label><input name="sex" type="checkbox" value="Female">Female</label>
    <p>Age</p>
    <label><input name="age" value="0-17" type="checkbox">- 18j</label>
    <label><input name="age" value="18-24" type="checkbox">18j - 24j</label>
    <label><input name="age" value="25-34" type="checkbox">25j - 34j</label>
    <label><input name="age" value="35-55" type="checkbox"><35j - 55j</label>
    <label><input name="age" value="56-100" type="checkbox">55j +</label>
    <a id="filter">Filter items</a>
</div>
```

The items are set up as follows, with the appropriate data-attributes the filters need to use:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item" data-sex="Male" data-age="22">
        Male / 22yo
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-sex="Female" data-age="35">
        Female / 35yo
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-sex="Male" data-age="17">
        Male / 17yo
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, filtering the items to exactly match the sex filters with the data attributes is fairly straightforward, and I was able to find a working solution to this in some other questions' answers. However, the tricky part is that the age filter values contain a range (with min and max age), and I have no idea how to set up the filters so it takes into account all filters, and only shows those items that meet each constraint.

It's important that if both sexes are checked, only the age filters should be taken into account, as there are no items that meet both sexes. But if only Male is selected, than only items with data-sex="Male" should be returned, that also meet the age filters if these are checked.

The code below is my jQuery code, but I don't know how to include the age filters.. The checked filters are correctly added to arrays (`sexes[]` and `ages[]`), and I can check the item data attribute against those arrays for the sexes, but I don't know how to do it for the ages range..

```
$('body').on('click','#filter',function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    
    $('.items .item').fadeOut(); // hide all items first
    
    var sexes = [];
    var ages = [];

    $('.filters input[name="sex"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           sexes.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $('.filters input[name="age"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           ages.push($(this).val());
        }
    });

    console.log(sexes);
    console.log(ages);

    $('.items .item').each(function() {
        if((sexes.indexOf($(this).data('sex')) > -1)) {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }
        //how to include the ages filters here..?
    })

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Split on `-`, convert to actual numbers, compare with `.data("age")`

Comment: The [oldest living person right now is 117](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_oldest_living_people). You might want to adjust your setup to include her as well.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thank you, this was the approach I thought of as well. Will try to implement that one. And thanks for the headsup haha, but this is a website for a personal trainer showing before-after pictures of clients, so I don't think I will need more than 100 :)

Answer (score 0):

To filter by age range, you need to break up the ages by the hyphen then compare the left and right side numbers to the age of the current item. Therefore, if minimum and maximum ages are within the current age, then it's true.

Next, there are ways to optimize your jQuery so you don't need so much code for collecting checked items. You can also get rid of `event.preventDefault();` by not using `.on('click','#filter',function()...`. Instead target the checkboxes directly.

If you do all this, then you get this code. I added comments to help you understand what is going on.

```js
// create a click listener on all input checkboxes
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  // gets all the checked sexes in an array
  var sexes = $('input[name="sex"]:checked').get().map(function(item) {return item.value});
  // gets all the checked ages in an array
  var ages = $('input[name="age"]:checked').get().map(function(item) {return item.value;});
  // loop through each item
  $('.items .item').each(function() {
    // shorten the reference to the current item
    var item = $(this);
    // returns boolean; if no sexes where selected, true; else check if the current item sex exists in the selected sexes
    var has_matching_sex = !sexes.length || sexes.indexOf(item.attr('data-sex')) > -1;
    // returns boolean; if no ages where selected, true; else check if the current item age exists in the selected ages
    var has_matching_age = !ages.length || ages.some(function(age_range) {
      // breaks the ages into an array and age to into a number. ex: "18-24" to [18, 24]
      age_range = age_range.split('-').map(function(age) {return Number(age);});
      // converts current item age into a number so it can be easily compared to the age ranges
      var age = Number(item.attr('data-age'));
      // checks if current age is greater than or equal to minimum age of age range.
      var is_min_age_match = age >= age_range[0];
      // checks if current age is less than or equal to maximum age of age range.
      var is_max_age_match = age <= age_range[1];
      // if both previous booleans are true, return true, else false
      return is_min_age_match && is_max_age_match;
    });
    // if both sex and age match
    if (has_matching_sex && has_matching_age) {
      // show the item
      item.css('display', 'block');
    }
    // se or age did not match
    else {
      // hides the item
      item.css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

jsFidde: https://jsfiddle.net/35s84vLo/1/